# Views in prototype UITableViewCell not visible in Storyboard on scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I'm making my prototype cells in Storyboard on UITableView. In some cases I have few tall cells. In this situation prototype cells which not visible firstly on UITableView don't update their content views.

This is the screenshot of UITableView top area:

[image: This is screenshot of UITableView top:]

And this when scrolling to middle:

[image: And this when scrolling to middle:]

Is there way to update UITableView/UITableViewCell content in Storyboard? Why this happens?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing scene size to freeform and resized it, so that all content became visible.